# How to use OpenCV on VisualStudio Code with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-code, cmake

Ok so i need help for my problem, i'm trying to run openCV on Visual Studio Code (windows),
here all the step i did :

I installed OpenCV, installed mingw64 and CMake.
After this i udpated my computer variable path and put in it :

C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
C:\Programmes(x00)\mingw64\bin
C:\Programmes(x00)\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib
C:\Programmes(x00)\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin

I created my cpp main file with this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    Mat img = imread("Chat.jpeg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(img.empty())
    {
        cout << "Could not read image: " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        imshow("Test",img);
    }
    
    return 0;
} 
`
```

and did my CMakeLists.txt too (with Visual Studio Code extention) with the code :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(monprojet VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(monprojet main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(monprojet ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

but visual studio code don't find my openCV include path

[Here you can see what happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga7Vw.png)

Error :

#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider parameter. Tildes are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\greenpenguin\Documents\project\main.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "opencv2/opencv.hpp"C/C++(1696)

thanks for read, i hope someone can help me

Comment: Did you use the cmaketools extension? [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)

Comment: Yes, i used it, here all extension i got :
C/C++ 
C/C++ Extension Pack
C/C++ Themes
CMake
CMake Tools